# How can I output a value to a specific line in Bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I print a value to specific line in Bash shell?
(For example, I would like to print a value up to the 10th line.)

Comment: 10th line of what? You mean take a value and extract its 10th line or first 10 lines or do you mean 10th line of the terminal?

Comment: If there are more than ten values, it means that only 10 values are output. (1 value has 1 line.)

Comment: @namsan You need to clarify your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62652459/edit) it. I was sure that you wanted to print a value on a specific line in your terminal window but now I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English. I think that your answer is right. @TedLyngmo

Comment: @namsan No problem, but be sure that my answer does what you like it to do before accepting it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not specific to `bash` but you can use `tput cup Y X` to set the cursor position:

```
tput sc         # save cursor position
tput cup 10 0
echo -n "hello"
tput rc         # restore cursor position
```

Comment: Much easier than `printf "\033[10;0H"` and `printf "\033[$((LINES-11))B"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed. Also, using raw escape seqences isn't good if the user is on terminal not recognizing the hardcoded sequences. A VT52 terminal (one of my old faviourites) wouldn't know what to do with that for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to show line numbers of the files, and grep it for the line:

```
$ cat test 
A
B
C
$ cat test -n |grep ^"     2"
     2  B

$ cat test2
A
B
C
D
E
F
$ cat test2 -n |grep ^"     4"
     4  D
```